# SP13: Recurring Calendar Event

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, calendar

I created a calendar in SP13.
Problem: For recurring events I will like for each event that's recurring to be listed out in the list view.  For example.  If I created an event to occur every 1st Friday of every month.  I would like to see every 1st Friday for every month to be listed individual on the list view.  To resolve: I have tried to create the recurring event and add each 1st Friday date for every month as a separate event.  This has worked but very time consuming.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you like to display calendar items in List view (content query web part), you need to use sp.js for recurring events. http://sharepointchan.blogspot.com/2011/10/situation-i-want-to-get-all-calendar.html

Comment: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/26/use-spservices-to-get-recurring-events-as-distinct-items-aspx/

Comment: @eVT Thank you! This is perfect! Note:  If you place your answer in the 'Answer' section I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to display calendar items in List view (content query web part), you need to use sp.js for recurring events.

http://sharepointchan.blogspot.com/2011/10/situation-i-want-to-get-all-calendar.html

More on this link.
http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/26/use-spservices-to-get-recurring-events-as-distinct-items-aspx/

```
var startDate = "2012-05-12T12:00:00Z"; // Our example will show the month of May 2012

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "My Calendar",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
        "</ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
                "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                        "<Month />" +
                    "</Value>" +
                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>",
    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" +
            "<CalendarDate>" + startDate + "</CalendarDate>" +
            "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
            "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
        "</QueryOptions>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var $node = $(this),
                fADE = $node.attr("ows_fAllDayEvent") || 0,
                thisADE = (fADE == 0),
                thisID = $node.attr("ows_ID"),
                sepID = thisID.indexOf(';#'),
                thisTitle = $node.attr("ows_Title"),
                thisRecurrence = $node.attr("ows_fRecurrence"),
                thisDesc = $node.attr("ows_Description");
            if (sepID != -1) thisID = thisID.substring(0,sepID);
            var thisUrl = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + thisID,
                thisClass = thisTitle.replace(" ","").substr(0,10).replace(",","").replace(" ","") + thisID,
                thisRD = $node.attr("ows_RecurrenceData");                                                        

            // if working with FullCalendar or building an events object for another purpose...
            events.push({
                title: thisTitle,
                start: $node.attr("ows_EventDate"),
                end: $node.attr("ows_EndDate"),
                allDay: thisADE,
                url: thisUrl,
                description: $(thisDesc).text()
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: can you tell us more about how/where to use these code?